# Почему на планшетах уведомления такого маленького размера?

Tags: android

Почему уведомления такого маленького   размера на телефонах все норм а на планшетах беда .

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Это стандартный размер, так и должно быть.

Answer (score 2):

Как уже говорил [@ЮрийСПб](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/17609/%D0%AE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%A1%D0%9F%D0%B1) это стандартный размер всплывающего уведомления и диалога. Для того чтобы всплывающее сообщение было нужного вам размера можно либо использовать библиотеку или создать свой собственный. Вот к примеру можно создать свой таким способом:

1. Создаем `custom_toast_layout.xml`:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/custom_toast_layout"
   android:background="@drawable/toast_round_background">
   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/custom_toast_image"
       android:layout_width="30dp"
       android:layout_height="30dp"
       android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
       android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
       android:maxHeight="20dp"
       android:maxWidth="20dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/custom_toast_message"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
      <TextView
       android:id="@+id/custom_toast_message"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
       android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
       android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
       android:fontFamily="@font/baloo"
       android:textColor="@android:color/white"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/custom_toast_image"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
   ```
2. Дальше создаем бэкграунд для этого сообщения в папке drawable `toast_round_background.xml`:
3. Третий пункт - создаем класс-помощник `KCustomToast.kt`:

   ```
        class KCustomToast {
   companion object {
       val GRAVITY_TOP = 48
       val GRAVITY_CENTER = 17
       val GRAVITY_BOTTOM = 80
       private lateinit var layoutInflater: LayoutInflater
       fun infoToast(context: Activity, message: String, position: Int) {
           layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
           val layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast_layout, (context).findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_layout))
           layout.custom_toast_image.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_information))
           val drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.toast_round_background)
           drawable?.colorFilter = PorterDuffColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.info), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY)
           layout.background = drawable
           layout.custom_toast_message.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
           layout.custom_toast_message.text = message
           val toast = Toast(context.applicationContext)
           toast.duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
           if (position == GRAVITY_BOTTOM) {
               toast.setGravity(position, 0, 20)
           } else {
               toast.setGravity(position, 0, 0)
           }
           toast.view = layout //setting the view of custom toast layout
           toast.show()
       }
       fun infoToast(context: Activity, message: String, position: Int, font: Typeface?) {
           layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
           val layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast_layout, (context).findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_layout))
           layout.custom_toast_image.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_information))
           val drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.toast_round_background)
           drawable?.colorFilter = PorterDuffColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.info), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY)
           layout.background = drawable
           layout.custom_toast_message.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
           layout.custom_toast_message.text = message
           font?.let {
               layout.custom_toast_message.typeface = font
           }
           val toast = Toast(context.applicationContext)
           toast.duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
           if (position == GRAVITY_BOTTOM) {
               toast.setGravity(position, 0, 20)
           } else {
               toast.setGravity(position, 0, 0)
           }
           toast.view = layout//setting the view of custom toast layout
           toast.show()
       }
   }
   ```

   }
4. Добавляем функцию вывода в активности:

   ```
     fun showInfoToastWithTypeface(view: View) {
       KCustomToast.infoToast(this, "This is a custom info Toast with custom font", KCustomToast.GRAVITY_BOTTOM, ResourcesCompat.getFont(context,R.font.bad_script))
   }
   ```
5. Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Ссылка](https://medium.com/@vijaymshr5/custom-toast-android-using-kotlin-and-constraint-layout-5bfdf2b8ac2b) на первоисточник. Так же если вам неохота долго засиживаться на создании всего того что я привел выше, то можно воспользоваться библиотекой. [Вот](https://github.com/topics/custom-toast) есть список на либы может что-то подойдет для ваших задач.